# Prove that $\dfrac{\sin{5x}}{\sin{x}}\in\left({-\dfrac54,5}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $\dfrac{\sin{5x}}{\sin{x}}\in\left({-\dfrac54,5}\right)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus{k\pi}$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I wrote $\sin5x$ as $5\cos^4x\sin{x}-10\cos^2 x\sin^3x+\sin^5x$ and now I need to prove that $5\cos^4x-10\cos^2 x\sin^2x+\sin^4x\in\left({-\dfrac54,5}\right)$, but it seems to be very difficult. Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\sin x\ne0,$

\begin{align}
\frac{\sin5x}{\sin x} &= 5\cos^4x-10\cos^2x(1-\cos^2x)+(1-\cos^2x)^2\\
&= 16\cos^4x-12\cos^2x+1\\
&= \left(4\cos^2x-\frac32\right)^2+1-\frac94
\end{align}

Since anything squared is $\ge0$, we have:

\begin{align}
0 &\le \left(4\cos^2x-\frac32\right)^2\\
1-\frac94 &\le \left(4\cos^2x-\frac32\right)^2+1-\frac94\\
-\frac54 &\le 16\cos^4x-12\cos^2x+1
\end{align}

Also as $\cos x\le1,$ $$16\cos^4x-12\cos^2x+1\le16-12+1=?$$

Comment: If we know that $a\le b$ how can we write $f(a)\le f(b)$? In this case we have $\cos{x}\le1$ then why $f(\cos x)\le f(1)$?

Comment: @Mathematician171, It holds only when $f(x)$ is increasing. Edited the logic as well

Comment: @Mathematician171 , $(4cos^2x−3/2)^2-5/4≤25/4-5/4=5$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $\left(4\cos^2x-\frac32\right)$ is not greater-than-or-equal-to $\frac94$. ($f(x)=x^2$ is not an increasing function.) However, it _is_ greater-than-or-equal-to $0$, which is all you need for this problem.

Comment: @columbus8myhw, Why did  not you put your answer separately?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Because you had done most of the work; I was just fixing a minor detail. (Also, I'm kinda lazy.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw, I hope this site is not for the lazy people. The difference is not "Minor". In future, please comment your observation before editing an answer

Answer (score 2):

The easy way: turn that into a polynomial by setting $t=\cos^2x$ (with $0\le t\le1$):
$$P(t)=5t^2-10t(1-t)+(1-t)^2=16t^2-12t+1.$$
This quadratic function achieves a minimum at $t=\frac38$, which is in range $[0,1]$, with value $P(\frac38)=\color{green}{-\frac54}$.

The values at the boundaries of the range are $P(0)=1$ and $P(1)=\color{green}5$.